# After a user downloads a file, IE9 thinks the entire site is a threat

Tags: security, internet-explorer-9

Before downloading the file, the site checks out fine. After downloading an .exe (non-malicious; an installer for an app used internally by website staff), the browser alerts:

> This website has been reported to
>   contain the following threats:
>
> - Malicious software threat: This site contains links to viruses or other
>     software programs that can
> - reveal personal information stored or typed on your computer to malicious
>     persons.

Checking on a different computer, the site is fine. After downloading the .exe, the same message appears again.

Why does this happen? More importantly, how do I prevent it from happening?

The same does not happen in Firefox or Chrome or Safari, using their similar malware-checking features.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so it's off-topic here.  Depending on what your perspective is, it would be better on webmasters.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the file that is being downloaded? If so, wrap it in compression (zip, rar, or something else). Browsers do not like .exe files being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make the user physically have a link to the download, in a compressed format would also help. A site that tries to send the user a *.exe file would look suspicious to any browser that cares at all for its user.